# What is this sign with red triangle and black bottom up "T" on cars in Lithuania?

Tags: automobiles, road-signs, lithuania

[image]

I have seen this sign mounted on the backs of some cars. But I could not find any information about it.

The upper end of the black part is spiky.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Given that very similar sign is employed in Russia, I would theorise it means that this car has little spikes built in its wheels' tyres, facing outwards. Spikes allow car to come to halt much faster in snowy weather, which may be of surprise for drivers of non-equipped cars.

[image: шипованная резина]

Spikes also supposedly damage roads' asphalt layer.

Please see [a page describing this sign](http://community.g-class.ru/index.php?/topic/7821-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5/&do=findComment&comment=190925) (in Russian).

The message descibes the season range when such tyres are allowed (1 Nov - 1 Apr), as well as features the sign itself.

Comment: You are right, but I still find the requirement or explanation a little bit odd. I regulary drive in many other European countries where studded tires are common and it is in other countries not common that cars with studded tires are required to carry a warning sign. No matter what stickers the car in front of you has on its back, you must expect it to be able to break more efficiently than you and keep distance.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I do also find it odd, but here we go. In Russia, btw, it's Ш instead of ⊥.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo this expectation generally fails the more east you move. Just look for news for big collisions and the number of cars involved. The more easter, the more the numbers.

Comment: Here's a site selling a magnetic plate with that symbol that implies it's for studded tires: https://aroste.lt/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=3035&language=en

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo What is common in one country is uncommon in another country. Different countries have different rules. This should not be surprising. Europe is not one "thing"; it's just a landmass.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica It is of course not surprising that countries have different rules, but that countries have a rule, for which I see no reasonable explanation. We could also require cars with relatively new tires, say less than 3 months old, to carry a warning sticker since these tires have a better road grip than older tires. We could require cars with anti-lock brakes to carry a warning sticker, since these cars stop quicker than other cars. We could require experienced drives to carry a warning sticker, since they are likely able to stop any car faster than other drivers.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo *shrug*. Why do we have [L plates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newly_licensed_driver_plate), when you're already best off assuming everybody else on the road i̶s̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶i̶d̶i̶o̶t can't drive?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Why do you ask me? When I learned to drive, there were no L plates either. In between, there are however so many warning signs pointing out even the most obvious and/or theoretical danger, that if a real danger should actually arise, you'll probably miss it, since you are busy reading the warning signs.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo actual fact: ABS helps you to steer better when you jam your foot on the brakes on a slippery surface. It also _lengthens_ the stopping distance since the brakes are only applied for part of the time (brake, lock, release, brake, lock, release, etc). The maximum braking efficiency (thus shortest stopping distance) is applying the brakes as hard as possible _without_ locking up in the first place. This is a skill that even pro racing drivers don't always master, so it's not quite as easy as it sounds.

Comment: @FreeMan And it is a skill, which most regular drivers don't master at all, at least not under preasure in an emergency situation, hence ABS will also reduce stopping distance on most surfaces for most drivers. The ABC 'cycle' you describe does on average give better grip and break force than trying to stop with locked wheels. When learning to drive, at a time when ABS was not common on all cars, we were taught cadence breaking as part of winter practice, a manual approach to the ABS cycle achieved by 'pumping' the break pedal as fast as possible instead of just stepping on it.

Comment: @FreeMan ABS is not only to shorten the stopping distance. It is also to be able to change the direction during stopping. So one hopeful could react at hindrances and go round.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question

Comment: @Tor-Einar Jarnbjo: This sign was introduced in then USSR in mid 80's and was made obsolete in Russia in 2018. Anecdotally, I've had damage to my windshield from loose studs twice in late 90's so I can kinda see merit in a sign like this.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Lithuania is not the only country with these kind of stickers. In Austria they are also mandatory for cars with spike tires. The stickers look different though: it's a red ring with eight black spikes (inverted Ts) sticking out of it.

Answer (score 20):

I can confirm that in Lithuania these are are used in the same way as alamar described.

See point 5 here: https://www.keliueismotaisykles.info/transporto-priemoniu-skiriamieji-ir-informaciniai-zenklai-transporto-priemonese.html (in Lithuanian). This is the official site for traffic regulations in Lithuania. It states the needed size for the sign, as well as that any car with spikes on the tires is required to have this sign on the back of the car.

Comment: Thank you for the source. I will use it for further questions of mine about car driving :)

Comment: the sign looks like "beware of tacks on the road", it may be worth knowing that other European countries use different pictograms for the same purpose, for example https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Spike-aufkleber.svg